# How to host an app on node server?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, debugging, web

I have a simple html file that refers to a CSS stylesheet and a javascript file. I'm supposed to host it on a node server. I Googled the procedure and surmised that I was supposed to include the files like so,

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var index = fs.readFileSync('index.html');
console.log(index);
var javaScriptFile = require('some/javascript/here');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'html'});

res.end(index);
}).listen(10024);
```

When I run the code, my HTML is rendered but my file treeStructServer.js is shown as an exact copy of the HTML, which causes an error. Any idea why that's happening? I'm out of my depth.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your current node script you just return the HTML file on every request, no matter what the URL is. You could instead use the node-static module. Install it by running `npm install node-static` and then replace your Node code with the following:

```
var static = require('node-static');

//
// Create a node-static server instance to serve the current folder
//
var file = new static.Server('./');

require('http').createServer(function (request, response) {
    request.addListener('end', function () {
        //
        // Serve files!
        //
        file.serve(request, response);
    }).resume();
}).listen(10024);
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Could you recommend any particular places to learn Node.js?

Comment: The tutorials I used to learn node aren't avaible anymore. Instead http://nodeschool.io/ seems to be the standard way to lear node nowdays.